# Azure Service Bus send csv rows to queue

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python

I am testing python SDK for Azure Service bus to send messages to the queue. The basic testing worked just fine, as I was sending a single string to the queue, as follow:

```
import csv
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

CONNECTION_STR = "CONN_STR"
QUEUE_NAME= "queue name"
def send_single_message(sender):
    message = ServiceBusMessage("Single Message")
    sender.send_messages(message)
    print("Sent a single message")


servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)

with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with sender:
        send_single_message(sender)
print("Done sending messages")
print("-----------------------")

with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
    with receiver:
        for msg in receiver:
            print("Received: " + str(msg))
            receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

Now the next step that I wanted to implement, was to loop through a csv file and for each row, send it to the queue.

so I tried to loop through this csv file, and send those rows to a queue. As follow:

```
def send_a_list_of_messages(sender):
    to_queue = []
    with open('final_result.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            to_queue.append(row)
    print(to_queue)
    message = [ServiceBusMessage(to_queue) for _ in range(len(to_queue))]
    sender.send_messages(message)
    print("Sent a single message")


servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)

with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with sender:
        send_a_list_of_messages(sender)

print("Done sending messages")
print("-----------------------")
```

But when I run my code, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "servicebus.py", line 23, in <module>
    send_a_list_of_messages(sender)
  File "servicebus.py", line 13, in send_a_list_of_messages
    message = [ServiceBusMessage(to_queue) for _ in range(len(to_queue))]
  File "servicebus.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    message = [ServiceBusMessage(to_queue) for _ in range(len(to_queue))]
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_common/message.py", line 110, in __init__
    self._build_message(body)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_common/message.py", line 190, in _build_message
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: ServiceBusMessage body must be a string, bytes, or None.  Got instead: <class 'list'>
```

I do understand that the services requires specific body type, but I was pretty sure that the `to_queue[]` was gonna be a string type.

Please, if anyone can help me to solve this problem I would be grateful.
And if you have any other question, please let me know.

Thank you so much

EDIT:

I come over the body type issue by converting the ServiceBusMessage to a string as follow:

```
message = [ServiceBusMessage(str(to_queue)) for _ in range(len(to_queue))]
```

but now I am getting an error about the size limit:

```
azure.servicebus.exceptions.MessageSizeExceededError: ServiceBusMessageBatch has reached its size limit: 262144
```

Can anyone help me with this.

I tried to process the workflow differently, in a way that the function should trigger multiple time for each row. as follow:

```
for msg in to_queue:
    print(msg)
    def send_a_list_of_messages(sender):
        print(to_queue)
        message = [ServiceBusMessage(str(to_queue)) for _ in range(len(to_queue))]
        sender.send_messages(message)
        print("Sent a single message")
```

But I get the same error.

I overcome the size problem temporarily by deciding to implement a for loop to trigger the function for each row in the csv file.

```
for msg in to_queue:
    # print(msg)
    def send_a_list_of_messages(sender):
        # print(to_queue)
        message = [ServiceBusMessage(str(msg))]
        sender.send_messages(message)
        print("msg sent: " + str(msg))
```

This works but partially, as the function sends only the last row in the csv file.

Comment: `But I get the same error.` - By this do you mean you are still getting `azure.servicebus.exceptions.MessageSizeExceededError`?

Comment: Yes. this is mainly because I am trying to send 4300rows at once, and that goes over the size limit set by the service. So for now, I decided to break the send function in a different way. So I set a for loop (I will update my Post with the code) that triggers that function for each row, but unfortunately this for loop sends only the last message and exits.

Answer (score 0):

1. ServiceBusMessage only accepts str/bytes, but originally you send in a list. If it is still failing after you cast to a `str`, there may be something else going wrong. Can you give a sample of your csv file?
2. A `MessageSizeExceededError` occurs when the size of list/batch of messages exceeds the maximum limit. You can read more about limits and batches here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusmessagebatch?view=azure-python.
   To ensure that you are not exceeding the limits and to send your batch of messages safely, you should instead use this pattern: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/ac60fb93ea23f32e5ed5a83532c1ed6aa49921b5/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/send_queue.py#L32

Please let me know if you have any questions!